# nodejs function exhausted all the memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, while-loop

I use below code to parse a Ascii Stl file(with coordinates of vertices) and output coordinate of each vertex. Though the Stl file is just about 30M, when the node script run, there is about 600M mem left on the system form the console

```
roofe@localhost:~/node$ ls -l DNA_mit_Anhnger.stl 
-rw-r--r-- 1 roofe roofe 34964929 Sep 27 09:50 DNA_mit_Anhnger.stl

~/node$ node test.js DNA_mit_Anhnger.stl 
vertex   4.893074e-001 8.750000e+000 2.695633e-001
free mem:: 557mb
vertex   5.357143e-001 8.750000e+000 3.077444e-001
free mem:: 557mb
```

while as the script running the mem will be exhausted out untile the system killed the script

```
Killed
roofe@localhost:~/node$
```

When the script running, I also use another terminal to check the system mem, (here is on the 2GB Mem Ubuntu16 Server LTS VMvare Machine)

```
 roofe@localhost:~/node$ ps v

   PID TTY      STAT   TIME  MAJFL   TRS   DRS   RSS %MEM COMMAND
  1064 tty1     S+     0:00      1   975 21492     4  0.0 -bash
 18623 pts/1    Ss+    0:00    715   975 21612     4  0.0 -bash
 19140 pts/2    Ss     0:00   1352   975 21604    16  0.0 -bash
 19482 pts/3    Ss     0:00   2594   975 21596  1124  0.1 -bash
 77681 pts/2    Rl+    0:19 120131 10894 2090529 737716 73.9 node
```

Here is the script,

```
var fs = require("fs");
var os = require('os');
var data = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);
var parseAscii = function(data) {
    var offset = 0;
    var str = '';
    while(offset = data.indexOf('vertex', ++offset)) {
        str =  data.substr(offset, data.indexOf('\n', offset) - offset);
        console.log(str);
        console.log('free mem:: ' + Math.ceil(os.freemem()/(1024*1024)) + 'mb');
    }
    console.log('finish');
}
parseAscii(data.toString());
```

Ascii Stl file format is like this,

> ```
> solid ascii
>   facet normal -6.343656e-001 -5.556834e-002 7.710334e-001
>     outer loop
>       vertex   4.893074e-001 8.750000e+000 2.695633e-001
>       vertex   5.357143e-001 8.750000e+000 3.077444e-001
>       vertex   5.077149e-001 8.785503e+000 2.872667e-001
>     endloop
>   endfacet
>   facet normal -7.010786e-001 -9.853018e-002 7.062440e-001
>     outer loop
>       vertex   4.616061e-001 8.782279e+000 2.410454e-001
>       vertex   5.077149e-001 8.785503e+000 2.872667e-001
>       vertex   4.526215e-001 8.846208e+000 2.410454e-001
>     endloop
>   endfacet
> ```

I've been work on the issue for whole afternoon, but find nothing, it almost drive me crazy.

Comment: when will your loop break? `indexOf` will return -1 if it does not find the string. `-1` evaluates to `true`

Comment: Yeah you're right, it will caused infinate loop. I also doesn't know why it will exhausted all the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop does not break on any condition. When the last `vertex` is processed, `indexOf` returns `-1` if it doesn't find anything. So offset gets set to -1 and while loop iterates indefinitely. All you need is to add a check to compare -1

```
while((offset = data.indexOf('vertex', ++offset))!=-1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I doesn't have much experience on js. I doesn't realize `indexOf()` has different output when find nothing like `substr()` of some other programming language which return False.

Comment: I also have some confuse here, though the infinite while loop, there shouldn't exhausted more mem as the while going on. There should only allocate fixed memory in the function.